# purpose of both cookies and session vs only cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, persistence

EDIT(13.07.10):

So the book just wanted to illustrate the functions of cookies vs sessions and the final example was combining the two of them. But it didn't really make much sense in a functional perspective. The final example was:

Set up cookies with the user_id, and also set up the session variable as the user_id. Because the session variable gets deleted when the browser closes, find out if the cookie is set and if it is set, copy the user_id to the session variable, to keep log in persistence longer than browser close.

Mind you, this is a beginner's book, not a truly functional/practical one.

DONE EDIT

I'm reading Head First PHP and the book talks about how superior the persistence is for using both cookies and session variables by resetting the session variables from existing cookie variables when you open up the browser again.

But when you think about it, what's the point of using sessions again in addition to cookies, if when you're using both the cookies are already exposed? That is, I'm not talking about session ID cookies here, I'm talking about just copying the cookie variables straight onto the session variables - not getting an address or anything like that.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This isn't completely clear.  Could you add code snippets to illustrate the comparison you're making?

Comment: the whole cookie data transfers from user to server ever page visit, you want the minimum amount of data you can getaway with in one for efficiency\security

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are visible to the end user, and the user can change them. If you need to store data that the user should not be able to view or forge, you should use sessions. Session data is stored on the server, not on the user's PC. Sessions make use of a single cookie, the session ID, which is just a random string that's used as a key into the session store. If the user modifies it, it will most likely result in a key that doesn't match anything -- it's long enough that it would be extremely difficult for them to guess the session ID used for some other user.

You can implement similar functionality with cookies by encrypting everything, but why go through all that work when you can just use sessions, which handle it for you? The only reason would be if your server resets sessions periodically, and you need persistence longer than that.

Comment: i assume he is a cookie expert based on the picture supplied

Comment: I thought sessions got destroyed/reset when the user closes the browser? How would I set the session persistence to indefinite, or something like that - until the user logs out, and disregarding the browser closing?